# Non-straight lines of symmetry

Tags: reflection, mirror-symmetry

This is a less concrete question I was just curious about. We always talk about straight lines of symmetry and reflections but can non-straight lines of symmetry exist when reflecting something, and if so what would they look like?

Logically, I'm not sure if it makes too much sense to ask something like this since I guess for some reflections, the reflection of an object could overlap with its own reflection but I'm asking just for the sake of maybe discovering something new. I guess it's also difficult to visualise what that would look like for example, what would the following circle look like when reflected across the red curve?

[image]

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Related notion: ["Parameterizing lines reflected in a parabola"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2953585/409)